# data does not appear correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am constrained in displaying the phone number using the scrapy spider, this should display the phone number, but it doesn't work, it seems like I have to click the "click to call" to display the number but when I add the css class that displays the phone number but it doesn't work
'Call': products.css('span.hz-pro-search-result__contact-info__cover::text').get(),

scrapy spider just prints "Click to call"
it should display a phone number

```
import scrapy

class houzzSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'houzz'
    start_urls = ['https://www.houzz.com/professionals/interior-designer']

    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.css('div.hz-pro-search-result'):
            try:
                yield {
                    # 'Name': products.css('a').find('span.header-5.text-unbold.mlm::text').get(),
                    'Call': products.css('span.hz-pro-search-result__contact-info__cover::text').get(),

                }
            except:
                yield {                   
                    'Call': products.css('span.hz-pro-search-result__contact-info__cover::text').get(),

                }
        next_page = response.css('a.hz-pagination-link.hz-pagination-link--next').attrib['href']
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: The phone numbers are hidden so if you want to see them and scrpae them you have to click on the "Click to call" and then you can get the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're trying to scrape is filled in using javascript when the "Click to call" link is used.

It is available in a huge (450kB) json blob that is included in the page source:

```html
<script id="hz-ctx" type="application/json">...</script>
```

If you load this data using the `json` library and figure out the path to the wanted data, you should be able to extract it without a problem.

Comment: can you tell me how to retrieve that data using "<script id="hz-ctx" type="application/json">...</script>"

Comment: `response.css('#hz-ctx::text').get()`